# Writing and Calling functions in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, function

this might be a stupid question, so if it is please feel free to troll in the comments. I have a sample code here that has a simple function in it. My question is: **once you have written a function (e.g. `myfunction(){}`) how do you call this without using `connectedCallBack()`?**

I have references to two code samples in the `JS` below. The first is the code I was able to get to run the function. The second snippet was my first attempt, but it failed to even save and deploy to SF due to syntax errors. I'm sure the solution is something simple, but have looked in the documentation and can't find anything on just `how to call a function in lwc without connectedCallback()`

Any help or clarity on this, would be great. Thanks.

### HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <div class="slds-m-around">
            {objectApiName}
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
    
</template>
```

### JS - This one works

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';

export default class TestObjectContext extends LightningElement {
    @api objectApiName;

    connectedCallback(objectApiName){
        this.checkObjectContext(objectApiName);
    }


    checkObjectContext(objectApiName){
        console.log(objectApiName);

    }
}
```

### JS  This one does NOT work, but I don't know why:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
    
    export default class TestObjectContext extends LightningElement {
        @api objectApiName;
    
        
        checkObjectContext(objectApiName);
        
    
    
        checkObjectContext(objectApiName){
            console.log(objectApiName);
    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @RenatoOliveria for the help on this (no pun intended :).

The issue appears to be related to what RO posted as an answer, the nature of functions returning values, and the LWC lifecycle.

### TL&DR

- Execution is not order dependent as mentioned above.
- Functions need to be assigned to variables like this var something = someFunction();
- Finally, the LWC lifecycle appears to require a connectedCallBack() function to be used in order to access public properties that are set after the initial run of the LWC constructor.

### JS Stuff

I was able to get this code to work. And this appears to be the best option because of the LWC LifeCycle. More on this later.

#### JS THAT WORKED

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';

export default class TestObjectContext extends LightningElement {
    @api objectApiName;


    connectedCallback(){
        this.objectApiName = this.checkObjectContext(this.objectApiName);

    }


    checkObjectContext(objectApiName){
        console.log('API NAME');
        console.log(objectApiName);

        return objectApiName;

    }

}
```

I was able to also get this function call to work. However, the value of `objectApiName` was `undefined`:

#### JS THAT KINDA WORKED (note: order does not matter. notice that the function is called before the checkObjectContext() is defined).

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';

export default class TestObjectContext extends LightningElement {
    @api objectApiName;

    objectApiName = this.checkObjectContext(this.objectApiName);

    


    checkObjectContext(objectApiName){
        console.log('API NAME');
        console.log(objectApiName);

        return objectApiName;

    }

}
```

What I read in a book on JavaScript yesterday came to mind after looking at RO's examples, that functions return values, and so I thought that I should attempt to assign the function to a variable; this got rid of the save issue I mentioned I was having. This is done above with the snippet `objectApiName = this.checkObjectContext(this.objectApiName);` However, due to the lifecycle events of lwc, ObjectApiName is not set yet, and so even though the function is being executed, it is not returning a value. This brings us to why use `connectedCallBack()`

### LWC LifeCycle and Decorators

This section explains why I think the objectApiName is not set when the function runs.
According to the LWC documentation

> The connectedCallback() lifecycle hook fires when a component is inserted into the DOM. [(Source)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks_dom)

If we look at this screenshot of the LWC flow (image below). We can see that the constructor runs first; now I have not called a constructor here, but it seems like there is still constructor that is running to create the HTML from the JS and `my hunch` is that whatever custom functions are declared will also be run during the constructor execution (please correct me if I'm off here). That being said, the property is then set after the function is executed, thus when the function is called the objectApiName is undefined.

Enter the `ConnectedCallBack()`. Since this runs after the properties are set, the function, in the correct/working code above, then has a value that it log out to the console of Opportunity or Contact or whatever object we are on. I'm not sure if this is 100% right, but will leave it to the community to correct me on that front.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This does not work mainly because you are trying to call an undefined function in your second example.

Try this in your browser:

```js
var f = function() {
    say('hi')
    let say = function(arg) { console.log(arg) }
}
```

You'll get a ReferenceError, because `say` is not yet defined when it is called:

> ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration `say' before initialization

In your first example the function is declared and compiled as part of your component before it is called by the framework (then it is defined).

If you declare the function before calling it, it should work:

```js
var f = function() {
    let say = function(arg) { console.log(arg) }
    say('hi')
}
```

```js
$ f()
>>> hi
```

---

But to answer your primary question on how to call a function without `connectedCallback`... you could take a look at the [wire service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/data_wire_service_about). It is supposed to be reactive, so that when a parameter changes the function is automagically called for your, which should include the moment when the component loads. I don't recommend it because it looks like wizardry to me, and I'd use the `connectedCallback` instead.

Comment: that makes sense as well. However I still get this error when trying to save the JS in LWC `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "{"`What I want to do is basically get the object information first and then have specific functions called to get specific data values from the object in question.

Comment: Got it to save by doing this ````checkObjectContext(objectApiName){
  console.log(objectApiName);

  return objectApiName;

 }
 objectApiName = checkObjectContext();````

Comment: However, SF is throwing an error now saying that the function is not defined.

Comment: Got with the this.checkObjectContext();